# How to perform array of array of hashes reordering in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an array as below:

```
product = [[{:pm=>61, :scs=>20,  :focus=>8}, {:pm=>61, :scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
[{:pm=>65, :scs=>20, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>65, :scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
[{:pm=>59, :scs=>20, :focus=>1}, {:pm=>59, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}], 
[{:pm=>60, :scs=>20,  :focus=>1}, {:pm=>60, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}],
[{:pm=>70, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>70, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
[{:pm=>85, :scs=>60,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>85, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
[{:pm=>72, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>72, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}]]
```

At one place I need to show the above list in a particular order,that order is getting based on a user interaction, that is, 'group_pm_list',and is given as a hash to follow to re-arrange the above array:

```
     group_pm_list={"8"=>[65,61],"1"=>[60,59],"10"=>[70,85,72]}
```

Here, we need to re-order the 'product'  based on the 'group_pm_list'(which is a sorted order of product list based on some filtration).

First, I need to get the key 8(:focus) with its 'pm' values 65, then , 61.
Secondly, I need to get the key 1(:focus) with its 'pm' values 60, then , 59.
Thirdly, I need to get the key 10(:focus) and within this group, the same order needs to maintain.

How can I generate a sorted list as given in the above order of **group_pm_list** to get the result as:

```
product = [[{:pm=>65, :scs=>20, :focus=>8},  {:pm=>65, :scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
           [{:pm=>61, :scs=>20, :focus=>8},{:pm=>61,:scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
           [{:pm=>60, :scs=>20, :focus=>1},{:pm=>60, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}],
           [{:pm=>59, :scs=>20,  :focus=>1}, {:pm=>59, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}],
           [{:pm=>70, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>70, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
           [{:pm=>85, :scs=>60,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>85, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
           [{:pm=>72, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>72, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}]]
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this data is an array of arrays? The very first thing you're doing with it is calling `.flatten`, which implies to me that the previous operation is returning an incorrectly formatted data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
product = [
  [{:pm=>61, :scs=>20,  :focus=>8}, {:pm=>61, :scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
  [{:pm=>65, :scs=>20, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>65, :scs=>23,  :focus=>8}],
  [{:pm=>59, :scs=>20, :focus=>1}, {:pm=>59, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}], 
  [{:pm=>60, :scs=>20,  :focus=>1}, {:pm=>60, :scs=>23,  :focus=>1}],
  [{:pm=>70, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>70, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
  [{:pm=>85, :scs=>60,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>85, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}],
  [{:pm=>72, :scs=>20,  :focus=>10}, {:pm=>72, :scs=>25,  :focus=>10}]
]

group_pm_list={"8"=>[65,61],"1"=>[60,59],"10"=>[70,85,72]}
```

#### Sol 1

```rb
group_pm_list.flat_map do |k, v|
  v.flat_map do |m|
    product.select { |n|
      n[0][:pm] == m
    }
  end
end
```

#### Sol 2

```rb
grouped_products = product.group_by {|elem| elem[0][:pm]}
group_pm_list.flat_map do |k, v|
  v.flat_map { |m| grouped_products[m] }
end
```

#### Sol 3

```rb
grouped_products = product.group_by {|elem| elem[0][:pm]}
group_pm_list.flat_map do |k, v|
  v.map { |m| grouped_products[m][0] }
end
```

Comment: Hardcoding `"8"` doesn't seem like a reasonable solution. You cannot assume that a specific number, like `8`, is in the sort order.

Comment: @TomLord that can come from request has the question specify there is a `:focus` number which will be there so that why I just harcoded it

Comment: OK, but it’s impossible to hardcore this in any real world solution. That’s why I said it’s not really a valid  answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very confusing way to define a sort order:

```
group_pm_list={"8"=>[65,61],"1"=>[60,59]}
```

1. Why are the keys strings, not numbers? I presume you actually meant to put numbers, and will be assuming that in the rest of this answer.
2. Are you sure it's not just "sort by `:pm` descending"?? This is a significantly more complex sort order...
3. Could you not define the sort order with a cleaner data object? That hash doesn't make any mention of `:focus` nor `:pm`, so it's a bit weird to "magically" know that's what it means.

I'll also assume you *flatten the array* at some point before using this answer, as it makes no sense for your data to be an Array-of-Arrays. Perhaps just call `product.flatten!` at the top, if mutating the variable is OK?

```
product = [{:pm=>61, :scs=>20, :bg=>"#a3ffff", :impact=>4, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>61, :scs=>23, :bg=>"#a3ffff", :impact=>nil, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>65, :scs=>20, :bg=>"#a3ffff", :impact=>nil, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>65, :scs=>23, :bg=>"#a3ffff", :impact=>nil, :focus=>8}, {:pm=>59, :scs=>20, :bg=>"#ffffd9", :impact=>nil, :focus=>1}, {:pm=>59, :scs=>23, :bg=>"#ffffd9", :impact=>4, :focus=>1}, {:pm=>60, :scs=>20, :bg=>"#ffffd9", :impact=>1, :focus=>1}, {:pm=>60, :scs=>23, :bg=>"#ffffd9", :impact=>1, :focus=>1}]

group_pm_list={8 => [65,61], 1 =>[60,59]}

focus_sort_order = group_pm_list.keys
pm_sort_order = group_pm_list.values.flatten

product.sort do |p1, p2|
  [
    focus_sort_order.index(p1[:focus]), 
    pm_sort_order.index(p1[:pm])
  ] <=>
  [
    focus_sort_order.index(p2[:focus]), 
    pm_sort_order.index(p2[:pm])
  ]
end
```

Comment: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer) from focus_sort_order.index(p1[:focus]),

Comment: @jissy Really? I just copy+pasted the code to my machine again to run it, and didn't see an error. Maybe you're still using the array-of-arrays without flattening it first, as I warned.

Comment: If you're wondering how this implementation works, see: https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:sort and https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E. The implementation is admittedly quite complex to understand, but that's unavoidable given the very weird/custom logic you're trying to apply here.